# Determine what bay a drive was inserted into

Tags: hard-drive

I have the unique problem of trying to figure out what drive bay a drive was inserted into given the disk's device name (e.g: `/dev/sdb1`).

***A little bit of background:***
The machine I'm working with has about 16 external drive bays and I need to be able to give the operator instructions such as: `Remove disk from bay #12`. At first I was mapping drive bay numbers to SCSI host port numbers but every time a drive is inserted into any of the bays, the SCSI host id changes (it increments). So my next plan is to map the drive bay numbers to a serial number (or other unique identifier) on the controller / SCSI bus. If a controller has more than one drive bay, I can use LUNs to differentiate them. However, I don't have a clue how to find this unique identifier.

***TLDR:*** So my question: given a device name (such as `/dev/sdb1`) how can I figure out what drive bay it's inserted into (assuming some kind of manual mapping has happened previously).